# undefined value when using ng-repeat in directive with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data structure that consists of a javascript object defining [a] branch of a tree-menu. One of it's properties is a 'subBranches' property which can be populated with other instances of the treeBranch class.

I have a $scope.branch = new treeBranch(), and I have added and defined the basic properties in 3 other treeBranch classes and added them as an array to the main branch, e.g.

```
$scope.branch = new treeBranch();
$scope.branch.label = "Main Branch";

var subBranch1 = new treeBranch(); subBranch1.label = "branch 1";
var subBranch2 = new treeBranch(); subBranch2.label = "branch 2";
var subBranch3 = new treeBranch(); subBranch3.label = "branch 3";

$scope.branch.subBranches = [ subBranch1, subBranch2, subBranch3 ];
```

I then have a block of html within my controller's container that defines a  with a call to the directive that should be drawing the subBranches:

```
<ul>
    <showbranch ng-repeat="subBranch in branch.subBranches"></showbranch>
</ul>
```

The problem is, I can't seem to see the iterator 'subBranch' variable in the directive no matter what I do. I have a scope: { 'subBranch' : '=' } and I have tried adding subBranch="subBranch" in the above  tag but no matter what I try, when I go into the directive (in the link code) and drop console for scope, I see the subBranch property but it is always 'undefined'. Meanwhile, the template does in fact draw three times so it is iterating over all three values in the array.

What am I missing?

SW

**EDIT:**

there is nothing fancy in the directive.

```
listsApp.directive(
    'showtype',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                subBranch : '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'showtype.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("showtype branch",scope);
            }
        }
    }
);


<script type="text/ng-template" id="showtype.html">
    <li>
        <span>{{subBranch.label}}</span>
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the directive code in your question. If you could include a working example in a plunkr that would help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have two issues that are unrelated.

The first is you have added your subBranches on the $scope as branch

```
$scope.branch.subBranches = [subBranch1, subBranch2, subbranch3];
```

While your template uses branches

```
<ul>
  <showbranch ng-repeat="subBranch in branches.subBranches"></showbranch>
</ul>
```

So, probably change your html to use `branch.subBranches`.

The second problem you will run into is that your directive doesn't actually know about the subBranch if you are creating an isolate scope with `scope: { 'subBranch' : '=' }`. This can be resolved by adding an attribute in your template that the directive is expecting. Since your directive scope just has `{ 'subBranch' : '=' }` it will need the attribute to be named `sub-branch="…"`. The directive will map the dashed attribute name to camelcase.

This can be easily added in your template:

```
<ul>
  <showbranch sub-branch="subBranch" ng-repeat="subBranch in branch.subBranches"></showbranch>
</ul>
```

Comment: woops, the branch vs. branches was a typo when transferring the code over. (it has been corrected and is correct in the actual code)

Comment: ahhhh, the camel-case tag was the problem. Changing it from subBranch="subBranch" to sub-branch="subBranch" did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the subBranch obj in the directive like

```
  <showbranch ng-repeat="subBranch in branches.subBranches" subbranch="subBranch"></showbranch>
```

Then you will be able to access it in the directive code.

```
app.directive('showbranch',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',

    scope:{
      subbranch:'=subbranch',

    },
    link:function(scope,element,attrs)
    {
      console.log(scope.subbranch);
    }
  }
})
```

sample plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Xj0RhGOthBLrNcbYwHm2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

ok, the camel-caseing of the attribute was what was throwing things off and using the hyphen or no camel case fixed it. My end result once I got that worked out was to again rename it to branch for the new directive so it could be handled in a similar fashion to the prior level:

```
    <li>Types:
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" title="Refresh" style="margin-left:15px;" ng-click="loadTypes()"></span><img src="<?= $loadAnim; ?>" ng-show="types.loading">
        <ul class="nobutton">
            <showtype ng-repeat="subBranch in branch.subBranches" sub="subBranch"></showtype>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

and then in the directive:

```
listsApp.directive(
    'showtype',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                branch : '=sub'
            },
            templateUrl: 'showtype.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("showtype branch",scope);
            }
        }
    }
);
```